# JXLS - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: jxls

I'm trying to use Jxls v2.2.5 to generate dynamic Excel files in my web application.
I receive this error.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jxls/area/Area : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I'm using java 1.6 for my development. Has Jxls compiled in a later version than 1.6 ? How can I get it run in java 6?

Comment: You can't.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error

Comment: So jxls is compatible with JRE 7. Can I get its source then compiled in java 6 & create a jar file ?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.  Looking over the jxls dependencies, I don't see anything that immediately stands out as needing Java 7, though you might run into compile errors with the source itself if they're using any new features.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Jxls2.0 doesn't support jdk6 yet.  You can still use jxls1.0 in the meantime which does support jdk6.

Upgrading from 1 to 2 isn't a big deal, just a little tweaking of your spreadsheet.

In the meantime, keep an eye out for the jdk libraries becoming available here:
https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/19/needed-compiled-on-jre-16-libraries